# Which are the Geojson css style properties for mapbox.js?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I try to style a LineString in a Mapbox Map through L.Geojson and all the style properties I could find are: *fillColor, colour, weight, opacity*.
Does anyone know if there is something else? For example to add a border width, a colour to this border, dashed the line, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- title
- description
- marker-size
- marker-symbol
- marker-color
- stroke
- stroke-opacity
- stroke-width
- fill
- fill-opacity

Mapbox.js uses the [simplestyle spec](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec/tree/master/1.1.0). That's where you can find out more about defaults and accepted values.

Adding a dashed line is a little more complicated, see [dashArray in the leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-dasharray) which will work with mapbox.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case of a LineString (or PolyLine for leaflet) loaded with L.geojson, the correct answer is the [Class Path](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path).

Comment: So how exactly can one add a border to a line string in Leaflet?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @araichev I don't know if you've figured out how to do that or not, but the way we are hacking it is to draw the GeoJSON once with an opaque background two pixels wider than the path, and then again with a semi-opaque background of our set color. Hacky, but it works.