# QGIS GeoJSON and color properties

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geojson, style

I have a GeoJSON file which is exported from a GIS system on odoo in GeoJSON format. I need to import it into QGIS. I tried a plugin called "Quick GeoJSON".

I copied and pasted the code and actually see the coordinate polygon. I'm also interested in displaying the colors found in the ""properties": " code but by importing I can't display them. Is there a way to automate this?

I show you the example JSON code.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        1658458.5605003895,
                        5028557.434750777
                    ],
                    [
                        1659101.4593532219,
                        5028315.519189377
                    ],
                    [
                        1659172.1561502179,
                        5028308.891340956
                    ],
                    [
                        1659200.8767002947,
                        5028395.0530754639
                    ],
                    [
                        1659249.4808377738,
                        5028450.284934948
                    ],
                    [
                        1659363.2583334693,
                        5028481.214767832
                    ],
                    [
                        1659424.0133789029,
                        5028487.8426162539
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "fill_color": "rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.2)",
                "fill_colorHexa": "#ff3333",
                "fill_opacity": "0.2",
                "stroke_color": "#ff3333",
                "stroke_width": "6",
                "image_radius": "7",
                "image_fill_color": "#33a7ff",
                "key_word": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm interested in the colors being read in QGIS as well.

Comment: GeoJSON does not have a normalized way to have style, it will depends of the GeoJSON provider and also the software reading the GeoJSON. That's why it needs to be done manually with QGIS. See also this other question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/geojson-styling-information